# Calling Variable from Form to Render Chart in Wordpress

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, variables

I am trying to use a Wordpress chart generation plugin, but call a variable that the user sets on the page. I've got the chart code in and it works at a rudimentary level and I was able to add a form to the page in which a user could enter a number and submit it, but the PHP code for calling the variable from the form breaks the chart code, I believe because the chart code looks for a ] character to determine where to conclude the chart script.

As follows:

Chart Code: `[easychart type="pie" height="100" width="100" title="U.S. Federal Expenditures, 2011 Fiscal Year" groupnames="Unfunded, Funded" valuenames="Unfunded, Funded" group1values="80" group2values="<?php ?get_percent = $_POST['percent']; echo$percent; ?>"]`

If I replace `<?php ?get_percent = $_POST['percent']; echo$percent; ?>` with 20, the chart works fine. Again, I believe it is because of the ] character after the percent POST command.

I'm probably barking up the wrong tree altogether. Basically I just want the user to be able to manipulate the chart.

Help?

Thanks

Comment: Please post a link to the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try changing: `group2values="<?php ?get_percent = $_POST['percent']; echo$percent; ?>"`
To: `group2values="<?php echo $_POST['percent']; ?>"`

Basically the first part (`?get_percent = $_POST['percent'];`) was unnecessary, and if you did need it, it should read `$get_percent = $_POST['percent'];`. You put a `?` instead of `$`.

Comment: Thanks Graham, but your suggestion still includes the closing ] character on percent, which interrupts the chart script. Is there any other way to pull the entered content from the form field?

Comment: I assumed you had checked this, but wordpress does NOT automatically run php that is inserted into posts. Can you copy the html source code (output)? I'm guessing the php isn't getting executed, and it's just showing up as plain text/html.

Comment: The rendered page shows '; ?>”]' after the error message for the chart script, indicating that it is terminating the chart script when it finds the first ] character. Is there a WP admin setting I should look into to ensure it processes the PHP component?

The comment editor doesn't allow enough room for me to paste the HTML code entered into the WP editor.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that php code does not execute in wordpress posts. There is an easy solution, but if you are new to php, I recommend you brush up on your php first. The solution is to install the following plugin which will enable the php in your post. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/

Comment: Thanks Graham. I installed Shortcode Exec PHP, which allows me to configure PHP snippets in a separate space and then call them with shortcodes. I ran a test where I created a new post containing the text field form and the PHP shortcode [percent1], but I stripped out the chart builder code. On testing if I entered 20 and then submitted the form, the page refreshed showing the number 20 at the location of the PHP call. That tells me that the PHP is processing fine. If I repeat the test with the PHP shortcode call nested in the chart code, it fails at the first ] character. Ideas?

Comment: Since the actual PHP code also contains a ] character, I'm not sure there's any way to do this. Basically, nesting a function that uses [] within a function that uses [] is breaking the outside function.

Comment: Google offers an AJAX chart builder. Maybe I should look into that?

Comment: Could you try `[easychart type="pie" height="100" width="100" title="U.S. Federal Expenditures, 2011 Fiscal Year" groupnames="Unfunded, Funded" valuenames="Unfunded, Funded" group1values="80" group2values="<?php echo 20; ?>"]`
That should let me know if the php code is executed before or after the chart is created. Also, could you please provide a link to where you downloaded the chart plugin? You could look into Google Charts.

Comment: Your code generates a chart without a 20% slice. I would guess this means the PHP code is executed after the chart. I installed the plug in from inside my WP admin area. Just did a search for "php" and selected the Shortcode Exec PHP item to install. I'm messing with Google Charts as well at the moment. What I had planned to do was have one field/slider that impacted two charts, such that when a user changed the value of the field, the two pies reflected the relative impact of that field. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hi Graham. Just in case you're monitoring this question, I've done some more work and made some progress and now need help understanding how to use a provided "Method" to call and embed a slider value into a chart function. Could you have a look at the following and share your thoughts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781489/passing-slider-value-to-other-functions