# Passing Slider Value to Other Functions

Tags: jquery, slider, var

I posted a similar question a few days ago and have done a bit more research and coding, and now I'm at a wall. I'm a complete newbie and needing more help.

I currently have one slider and two charts successfully rendering on the same page. I'd like to pass the value of the slider into the two chart functions such that as the slider is moved, the charts refresh. The slider is generated using the jQuery UI function. The charts are generated by the Highcharts function.

There is a "Method" in the jQuery Slider API called "value()" that will retrieve the value of the slider, as follows:

```
var selection = $( ".selector" ).slider( "value" );
```

Currently, the values for the charts are hard coded as numbers within the function code for the charts. I'd like to dynamically update the values for the charts based on the value of the slider.

Ideas?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Could you please post your code, as it makes it easier to help you?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the change function in the jquery UI documentation

```
$(function() {

    $("#slider").slider({
     change: function (event,ui){
      // your code here
    }
});
});
```

this should work for every time there is a change in your  slider

---

this is how your code should look like

```
 change: function(event,ui)
      {
        $( "selector" ).val( ui.value );
      }
```

Comment: So do I nest the chart functions inside the change event? And then how do I code within the chart functions to absorb the current value of the slider?

Comment: You can pass the value of the slider by calling the chart generating function inside the change functon

Comment: Embedding the chart code inside the {} characters after the change function breaks everything. The slider nor the charts work. Moving the chart code back outside the change/slider function restores everything.

Comment: I have added an example for u to understand

Comment: There is another Event called "slide" that returns the value of the slider continuously, as long as the mouse is moving. In the example slider I have, this Event is used to populate a DIV with the current slider value. I nominally understand the syntax used to "call" the slider value into the DIV on the page, but how would I "call" the slider value into the chart script in the HEAD?

Comment: what exactly do u mean by chart script . is it a function populating a div or something else . you could use slide or change depending on what you want

Comment: There are three scripts running, 1x slider and 2x chart. The slider script renders the slider as well as a DIV that contains the value of the slider. The chart scripts are just rendering charts that reflect static values entered into the script code. I'm trying to design a way to have one pie slice of the charts reflect the value of the slider.

Comment: Ok , first off , the HTML does not see it as three different scripts , all the code in the script tags are rendered as a single doc by the browser . now with the modified code I had written , the selector (could be class or id name of your div element) , the code populates the value of the slider into whatever element u choose to put in the slider

Comment: Understood, but I don't want to put the value of the slider into a DIV. I want to put the value into the chart scripts. My best guess is that I would have to set up the slider value as a variable that the chart scripts would "call" before they were processed...

Comment: exactly , u have to pass the value of your slider to the script function